# How to display a table with dynamic columns in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, gridview, data-binding

I have a list of object, each object contains user defined attributes. The keys and values for these attributes are free string, so they are not necessarily consistent between objects. Regardless, I would like to display all my objects in a table.

One object per row, one attribute key per column, one attribute value per cell like so :

| name | age | favourite fruit | favourite color | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | 21 |  | blue | london |
| jane |  | ananas | red | paris |
| paul | 22 | banana | green |  |
| patricia | 23 | ananas |  | istanbul |

I have a custom objects responsible for reading the attribute and storing them in a `Dictionary<string, string>` and my model view stores a list of such dictionaries. I would like to link this list of dictionary to my WPF control.

Later, column would need to be sortable and groupable by attribute value (like excel subtotals)

I don't even know where to start ? Custom dataGridView ? Custom ListView?

Comment: The DataGrid does not know how to handle a Dictionary. It can handle a list of (row) objects or a DataTable. If you have a dynamic table where column names or column count are changing at runtime you would use a DataTable as items source. You must convert your Dictionary to a proper data structure before assigning it to the DataGrid.ItemsSource. If you use data binding you could also implement the data structure conversion in an IValueConverter. Why did you choose a Dictionary as data structure in the first place? It's not doing you any favor, does it?

Comment: @BionicCode, Dictionnary seemed like a cheap way to store my key/values,and I am only using it as an interface between the original data and the display. I am not married to it though...

Comment: You should always chose the best data structure that expresses the relationship of your data the best. If you have loose key-value pairs then a collection of KeyValuePair is best. If you need fast lookup based on a key (and not by index) a Dictionary is the structure of choice. But this doesn't seem to be your concern. In your case the key-value pairs have a relationship with each other: N key-value pairs make a set (a row). Building a data table from a dictionary is of course not a problem but very awkward.

Comment: You must make a decision whether to create a data model to express the relationship of your data or a DataTable. And unless you need the key based lookup, don't use the Dictionary at all to avoid the conversion. Note that you can lookup up data in a DataTable by column where the column name serves as the lookup key of a row. Using a list of Dictionaries is very odd in your situation. I'm pretty sure you can't justify such a structure. At least a Dictionary where the key is the column name and the value a list of values for this column where each item in this list maps to an individual row.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to get rid of the dictionnary conversion step entirely and go Model>DataTable>UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DataTable` object is the way to go for dynamic data. You will have to convert it by doing something similar to what is below, but instead iterating through your objects.

#### Window xaml.cs

```cs
    public partial class DataGridFromDictionary : Window
    {
        public DataTable Table { get; set; }
        public DataGridFromDictionary()
        {
            var attributeDictionaries = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>()
            {
                new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    {"name", "john" },
                    {"age", "21" },
                    {"favourite color", "blue" },
                    {"city", "london" },
                },                
                new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    {"name", "jane" },
                    {"favourite fruit", "ananas" },
                    {"favourite color", "red" },
                    {"city", "paris" },
                },
            };

            Table = CovertToDataTable(attributeDictionaries);

            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
```

#### `Dictionary` to `DataTable` converter

This will allow you to convert your data into something that the `DataGrid` can consume.

```cs
        public DataTable CovertToDataTable(List<Dictionary<string, string>> dynamicObjects)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            foreach(var attributeDictionary in dynamicObjects)
            {
                // add any missing columns
                foreach (var attribute in attributeDictionary.Keys)
                {
                    if (!table.Columns.Contains(attribute))
                    {
                        table.Columns.Add(attribute);
                    }
                }

                // create the new row
                var dr = table.NewRow();

                foreach (var attribute in attributeDictionary)
                {
                    dr[attribute.Key] = attribute.Value;
                }

                table.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            return table;
        }
```

#### xaml

```xml
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Table}" />
    </Grid>
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: This works for me, Thanks a lot @Egeer ! I'll leave the question open for a day and mark this answer as accepted if nothing else shows up :)