# Dynamically creating GridView from an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

In my C# / WPF application, I have a `ListView` that I want to use as a `GridView` to display items in a table:

```
<ListView x:Name="Table_ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Conditions}"/>
```

It is binded to a `ObservableCollection<Condition>`, where `Condition` is defined like this:

```
public class Condition
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }

    public class Property
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

(Please note that I skipped `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation here to simplify this example code).

Idea is that GridView Column headers should display `Name` property of instances of `Condition`, while row headers should display `Name` instance of Property, and the cells - the `Value`. It is expected that all `Condition` instances will have the same number of Property instances with the same names. So for example if we have this method that creates sample data:

```
private ObservableCollection<Condition> CreateConditions()
{
    ObservableCollection<Condition> conditions = new();

    conditions.Add(
    new Condition()
    {
        Name = "c1",
        Properties = new() 
        {
            new() { Name = "p1", Value = 5 },
            new() { Name = "p2", Value = 10 },
            new() { Name = "p3", Value = 15 },
        }
    });

    conditions.Add(
    new Condition()
    {
        Name = "c2",
        Properties = new()
        {
            new() { Name = "p1", Value = 8 },
            new() { Name = "p2", Value = 12 },
            new() { Name = "p3", Value = 20 },
        }
    });

    conditions.Add(
    new Condition()
    {
        Name = "c3",
        Properties = new()
        {
            new() { Name = "p1", Value = 11 },
            new() { Name = "p2", Value = 17 },
            new() { Name = "p3", Value = 25 },
        }
    });

    return conditions;
}
```

Then the GridView table should look like this:

```
-   c1  c2  c3
p1  5   8   11
p2  10  12  17
p3  15  20  25
```

Since I'm trying to use MVVM, the view model looks like this:

```
public class TableResultsViewViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Condition> Conditions { get; set; }

    public TableResultsViewViewModel(ObservableCollection<Condition> conditions)
    {
        this.Conditions = conditions;
    }
}
```

And the main class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private TableResultsViewViewModel vm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ObservableCollection<Condition> conditions = CreateConditions(); //sample data creation method from before
        vm = new TableResultsViewViewModel(conditions);
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to properly declare the ListView in WPF so that it would dynamically generate these columns and rows as the `ObservableCollection<Condition> Conditions` changes (instances of `Condition` added or removed from this collection, or instances of `Property` added or removed from `Properties` list inside the instances of `Condition`). Has anyone done anything similar and could help me out?

EDIT: I am not particularly bound to use ListView/GridView. DataGrid is also acceptable. I just used GridView in my current attempt.

Comment: it is great to see that nowadays WPF is in such a high demand that a question with 20 views gets 4 upvotes, on weeken no less

Comment: If you have dynamic creation of columns and rows (that is, you do not know how many columns there will be during development and this information becomes known only at runtime), then I would advise you to use DataTable instead of ObservableCollection<Condition>.

Comment: @EldHasp Okay, that makes sense, but I am unsure on how to define that DataTable in such a way that it would automatically update if the underlying collections or properties of their members are updated.

Comment: You must use a `DataTable` as your primary data structure. If you want to display data as a table then a `DataTable` might be the best data structure to work with, at least in the UI context. You can always load data into a `DataTable`, display it, let the user edit it, and in the end convert it back to the original format if your data layer can't handle `DataTable`. `DataTable` is the only convenient way to generate a table dynamically, especially dynamic columns. You can easily add a new column to a `DataTable`. But you can't just do that with a property definition (that's not simple at all)

Comment: If your columns are not based on the properties of a type you can make use of the DataGird's feature to autogenerate columns. And you can always programmatically define the layout of the DataTable or ListView.

Comment: What you can do is that you add a new Condition that will generate a new column (it's possible) but with different cell count. Then you would have to add cell values to the other rows too. The point is that your current data structure is column based while the data tables in general are row based. I think that's the main issue here. Each row must have the same number of cells. You must invert/rotate your data structure. For example, instead of thinking of "c1" as a column of vertical "5 10 15" they must make a row of horizontally "5 10 15". You must swap "C1" with "P1"  so that C1 makes a row.

Comment: @JustinasRubinovas , I would go deeper. You have some “initial data” that you parse into the Conditions collection. Perhaps you should make changes at the stage of parsing this data and create a more convenient reflection based on it.

Comment: You can also configure autoparsing of Conditions in DataTable, but there are too many uncertainties in the implementation that you showed. First of all, I'm interested in the mutability of Condition after adding it to the collection. If they are immutable, then creating an auto-conversion will not be a problem. You can do without the DataTable by creating your own Custom Control based on the horizontal ItemsControl or Selector.

Comment: @JustinasRubinovas, this solution might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77789748/15534202