# Nested list binding in dataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am looking for a solution to bind nested list to DataGrid to display them in separate columns.

ViewModel

```
public class ParametersDataGridViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
public ObservableCollection<Row> RowsList { get; set; } = new();
}
```

```
public class Row
{
        public string NameColumn { get; set; }
        public bool IsCheckedColumn { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Values> ValuesColumns { get; set; } = new();
}
```

```
public class Values
    {
        public string ValueName { get; set; }
        public List<string> ValueValue { get; set; }
    }
```

My goal is to get DataTable like below for sample data:

```
RowsList.Add(new Row{NameColumn = Name1, IsCheckedColumn = TRUE, ValuesColumns = new Values{ValueName = "ValueName1", ValueValues = {1,2,3}});
RowsList.Add(new Row{NameColumn = Name2, IsCheckedColumn = FALSE, ValuesColumns = new Values{ValueName = "ValueName2", ValueValues = {4,221,231}});
RowsList.Add(new Row{NameColumn = Name3, IsCheckedColumn = TRUE, ValuesColumns = new Values{ValueName = "ValueName3", ValueValues = {34,43,213}});
```

[image: desired result]

So far I tried following solution but it is not what I need because number of ValuesColumns is variable and I don't want to declare it in that way because columns may be added or removed dynamically.

UPDATE
Thanks for all responses. Mentioned solutions are good direction but they are not cover fully my exceptions. I am wondering how I can get checkBox in Column Ischecked value. Right now I passing Dictionary<string, string>. I have checked and It is possible to change it to Dictionary<string, object> (during creation i can add for example Dictionary<string, string> and Dictionary<string, bool> to the List<Disctionary<string,object>>) but unfortunetly converter will cast it to string (DatTable will show TextColumn not CheckBoxColumn). I need it because in my final table i want to have there checbox or button binded to ICommand in my ViewModel and as parameters I want to pass whole row.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78134318/dynamically-creating-gridview-from-an-observablecollection

Comment: Check out this solution that shows how to iterate through a dictionary to create a DataTable https://stackoverflow.com/a/77789748/15534202

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display a table with dynamic columns in WPF MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77788478/how-to-display-a-table-with-dynamic-columns-in-wpf-mvvm)